# Designing a hash function that creates keys for a hash table from an alphanumeric number

Tags: hash, alphanumeric

I am trying to design a hash function using customer IDs that range from AA0001 to ZZ9999.
The keys will be stored in a one dimensional array. 
Each element of the array will need to be accessed.
My thinking is that I can sum the ascii values of the customer ids as well as the following numbers. 
I am planning to have an array size of 100. 
I am new to this subject so not clear whether my thinking is correct. 
The smallest number is AA0001 conversion of Ascii of AA is 130 and 1 makes smallest limit to be 131.
Maximum number ZZ9999 is 180 + 9999 = 10179. 
I am want to use modulus function but not sure how to use this function to give me a range of numbers between 1 to 100.

Comment: Any positive integer mod 100 will give you a number in the range 0 to 99. Just add one, and you get a number in the range 1 to 100.

Comment: Thanks, it was the evaluation of the numbers that create the positive integer that confused me but it seems clear now.